# how to return response string from $http get request

Tags: angularjs, httpwebresponse

I want to get dynamic string response from the server by sent date of an object.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
                                        let tempNotification = { ...notifications[i] };
                                        tempNotification.Time = convertTime(tempNotification.CreationDate);
                                        tempArray.push(tempNotification);
                                    }
```

This is the convert Function:

```
 function convertTime(date) {
                    const today = new Date();
                    const creationDate = new Date(date);
                    const months = today.getMonth() - creationDate.getMonth();
                    //if hours / 24*30 - moth
                    if (months > 0) {
                        return new Date(date).toLocaleString();
                    } else {
                        const sum = today.getDate() - creationDate.getDate();
                        if (sum > 0) {
                            return sum + " " + GetSpecificReactConst("notification-days-ago");
                        } else {
                            const hours = today.getHours() - creationDate.getHours();
                            if (hours > 0) {
                                return sum + " " + GetSpecificReactConst("notification-hours-ago");
                            } else {
                                return 1 + " " + GetSpecificReactConst("notification-houts-ago");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and the GetSpecificReact... is an $http get request:

```
  function GetSpecificReactConst (text) {
                    $http.get(AppConfig.apiUrl + 'Translations/GetSpecificReactConst?constKey=' + text + '&lang=' + $location.url().split('/')[1]).
                        then(function (response) {

                        });
                }
```

How i can get the response?